# Make hashtag url with AJAX load directly on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im building a website with a hashtag AJAX system.

Each page has a hashtag. For example:

```
<a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
```

It all works almost fine. Problem is, its not working smoothly.

If I press Page 2 nothing happens but the URL changes to #page2. Then press Page 1, the URL changes to #page1 but instead of Page 1 showing Page 2 is displayed.

Also, when I go to `index.php` I want it to redirect to the home hashtag page. For example. `index.php#home`

That doesn't seem to work either.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if(window.location.hash == ''){

        document.getElementById('link_hem').click();

    }

    //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('active');

    //Seearch for link with REL set to ajax
    $('#menu a').click(function () {

        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;

        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        //hide the content and show the progress bar
        $("#menu img#logo").attr("src", "ajax/loader.gif");

        //run the ajax
        getPage();
    }); 
});


function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}

function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    var page = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/retriever.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //hide the progress bar
            $("#menu img#logo").attr("src", "images/menu_logo.png");    

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
            $('#page').html(html);

        }       
    });
}
```

How do I make the act on the click? If i click Page 1 or enter #page1 in the URL i want the content of page1 to display directly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called a document fragment identifier, not a hashtag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by passing the variable hash to the function and use it as the data retriever.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if(window.location.hash == ''){

        document.getElementById('link_hem').click();

    }

    //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('active');

    //Seearch for link with REL set to ajax
    $('#menu a').click(function () {

        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;

        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        //hide the content and show the progress bar
        $("#menu img#logo").attr("src", "ajax/loader.gif");

        //run the ajax
        getPage(hash);
    }); 
});


function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}

function getPage(hash) {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=%23' + hash;
    var page = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/retriever.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //hide the progress bar
            $("#menu img#logo").attr("src", "images/menu_logo.png");    

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
            $('#page').html(html);

        }       
    });
}
```